# jQuery click event needs 2 clicks in second bind event to fire

Tags: jquery

I am tring to fire 2 events on a single click.

Please see this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/JohnHalsey/g2tAN/5/).  The user should be able to click repeatedly to get the arrow to spin round, and the div to move over, and then move back.

The first bind event works fine and the arrow spins round, but the div wont start moving over until the second click.

HTML

```
<div class="arrow">
            <img src="http://www.avenir-telecom.co.uk/common_files/images/right-arrow.png" alt="Click here to show contracts" id="arrow"/>
</div>
<div id="page">
    <h1>Some Heading Here</h1>
    <p>This is some text to make the div look normal</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.arrow
{
    float: left;
}
#page
{
    width: 400px;
    position:relative;
    background-color: #1371BE;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 35px;

}
```

jQuery

```
$(function ($) {
    var value = 0;
    $('img#arrow')
    .bind('click',function(event){
       value += 180; 
       $(this).rotate({animateTo:value}, 300);
    })
    .bind('click',function(event){
        var x = $(this).data('open');
        $('#page').animate({
            left: (x) ? '100px' : '0',
            load: true
        }, 300);
        x ? $(this).data('open', false) : $(this).data('open', true);
    });

});
```

It must be something simple!

Comment: Why are you chaining 2 `bind()` handlers for the same event?

Comment: Why do you need to differentiate those two functions ?

Comment: I think that `$(this).data("open")` is undefined on the first click. Also you should group your bindings in one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to verify if `x` is `undefined` and if so, set it `true`.

```
if (x === undefined) x = true;
```

[**JFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/g2tAN/7/)

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
    $('#page').animate({
        left: (!x) ? '100px' : '0',
        load: true
    }, 300);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2tAN/6/

I combined the 2 binds into 1, there is no point doing 2 different binds. Also added a `!` to the left. I think you had it backwards there that's why it was not working properly

Comment: I did try and do it like that but couldn't get my head around it.  Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add `.data("open", true)` so that it is defined.

```
$('img#arrow').data("open", true)
.bind('click',function(event){
   value += 180; 
   $(this).rotate({animateTo:value}, 300);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/prankol57/ZK6Pd/

Also, your `open` seems backwards. Shouldn't it open if open was previously set to false?